# Объединить метки про автозагрузку

Tags: предложение, метки

Предлагаю объединить метки [Автозагрузка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0) и [Автозапуск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA). `Автозагрузка` оставить основной меткой, `Автозапуск` в синонимы.

Comment: А может, заменить на метки, соответствующие ОС, и грохнуть обе?

Comment: @D-side в принципе можно, но опять ведь появятся, или есть механизм для предотвращения создания меток которые были удалены ранее?

Comment: Есть, но задействуется редко и свыше. Да и обычно хватает предупреждения в кратком описании. Но чтобы у метки было описание, она должна быть у вопросов, так что... Их придётся (?) оставить. Только собрать описание. Синонимизировать... Не уверен. Пока что просто вношу дополнительное направление для размышлений.